# Read Data from CSV and change it to tuple using Python 3.7

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tuples

I read data from CSV file and convert it to tuple using code below

```
with open('data.csv') as f:
     data=[tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(f)]
```

output data is like below:

```
data=[('A1231',),('B1256',),('A4152',),('D1254',)]
```

I need to have data like :

```
data=['A1231','B1256','A4152','D1254']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `tuple`, use slicing instead:

```
with open('data.csv') as f:
    data = [line[0] for line in csv.reader(f)]
```